# Django SMTP Send Email Configuration

Tags: django, django-email

I already setup the email. It was working perfectly but after sometime it is not working and sending the mail. I don't know where the problem was created. Can someone help me out with this??

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypass'
```

this is my email function code:

```
def my_email():
    order = Order.objects.filter(createdAt__gt=Now()-timedelta(minutes=1))
    p = str(settings.BASE_DIR)
    with open(p + '/templates/email.html') as f:
        order_message = f.read()
    for o in order:
        print(o._id)
        email = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject='Thank you', body=order_message, from_email='laksura.com.bd@gmail.com', to=['sohanur.shanto@northsouth.edu'] )
        html_template = get_template('email.html').render()
        html_template = render_to_string('email.html', {'name': o.user, 'order_id': o._id, 'total': o.totalPrice, 'created': o.createdAt})
        email.attach_alternative(html_template, "text/html")
        email.send()
```

I am getting this error

```
new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py", line 62, in open
    self.connection = self.connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\smtplib.py", line 255, in __init__     
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\smtplib.py", line 341, in connect      
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)     
  File "C:\Python39\lib\smtplib.py", line 312, in _get_socket  
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,     
  File "C:\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 843, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 831, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Answer (score 0):

Gmail blocks the use of Gmail by less secure apps by default. You will have to change this setting if you have to use Django-mail.

[image]

If you don't change this setting, Gmail won't allow your account to send mail via your Django web app.

Comment: I already changed it. But it is not working though. Sometimes it is working and sometime it is not working.